# How to disable backdrop and close previous open modal in react-modal

Tags: reactjs, react-modal

Am using [react-modal component](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal),

> 1. I don't need backdrop in certain scenarios, how do I disable the backdrop. Don't see any property in the documentation.
> 2. How do I close any previous modal's if opened, whenever a new modal is opened.

Answer (score -1):

1) If you don't need backdrop you can always pass the style prop to react-modal:

```
style={{overlay:{backgroundColor:"rgba(0,0,0,0)"}}}
```

Taking a look at the code the default style overlay has a backgroundColor rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75).

2) If you want to close other modals when a new one is opened you can just change the value of the isOpen prop:

```
isOpen={this.state.showModalOne}
```

When you open the ModalTwo you will call:

```
this.setState({showModalOne:false, showModalTwo:true});
```

If modals are in different components you can work with props.
You can even choose to not close the modal but change only its content.